# Can I add an application button to Plank?

Tags: appmenu, plank

`Applications` button in the `Plank Docklets` doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.
How can I add an application button to Plank? (performs same as <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Comment: what desktop environment are you using? default GNOME?

Comment: @SkanderBejaoui yes, GNOME.